# How to include credentials in fetch/preload with Svelte/Sapper?

Tags: fetch, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

## Setup

I have a typical web app setup:

- A backend service running at `https://mybackendsvc.com`
- Users are authenticated with `mybackendsvc.com`, and have a session cookie.
- Svelte/Sapper running at `https://myfrontend.com`

I'm using Sapper `preload` to fetch some data from `https://mybackendsvc.com`. Here's `routes/mydata/[id].svelte`:

```
<script context="module">
  export async function preload(page, session) {
    const res = await this.fetch(
      `https://mybackendsvc.com/api/public/${page.params.id}`,
      {
        credentials: 'include' // sends the session cookie to mybackendsvc.com
      }
    );
    if (res.status == 200) {
      let myData = await res.json();
      return { myData };
    } else if (res.status === 401) {
      this.error(401, "Unauthorized");
    } else {
      this.error(500, "Something went wrong");
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let myData;
</script>

<div>
  {myData}
</div>
```

Note the use of `fetch` with credentials included:

```
{
  credentials: 'include'
}
```

## The problem: Where "preload" executes matters

If a user navigates to `mydata/[id]` directly, `preload` runs on the node server, Sapper doesn't include the user's session cookie (likely because the node server doesn't have access to it), so `mybackendsvc.com` responds with `401`. **However** if a user navigates to `mydata/[id]` via a link inside my app, `preload` is run browser-side, the browser includes the session cookie, and the call succeeds.

How can I make Sapper guarantee that `fetch` includes credentials in an api call? Or can you not use `preload` with authenticated API calls, only public API calls?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899648/306520
It kinda answers your question too I think

Comment: Does not answer my question. The "proxying" hack suggested here adds another layer of misdirection but still provides no guarantees _where_ the code will run (browser or server) and _what_ it will have access to (cookies or not).

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to only make requests from the browser.

Comment: I agree. Is there a way to configure Sapper to not attempt requests server-side?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem yet, Nate? I'm running into it currently

Comment: @EddyVinck I'll bet you already figured this out but for anyone who comes across this post in the future, here's what I've done to guarantee certain requests only run client-side, in `preload()`: `const isClient = typeof window !== "undefined"; if (isClient) { //do requests }`

Comment: @dirkenstocks unfortunately I don’t think I did, but I also haven’t used Svelte in quite a while so I might have forgotten. Good luck!